# Cordova 3/Phonegap 3 install plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, osc

I'm currently building an application which should send messages via OSC protocol to Grasshopper (to Rhino 5).

I installed the OSC cordova plugin (https://github.com/sy1vain/cordova-osc-plugin) via cordova plugin add.

This all seems to work. The javascript class looks like this

**OSCSender**

```
var OSCSender = function(host, port){
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
}

OSCSender.prototype.send = function(address, data, successCallback, errorCallback){
if(typeof data == 'function'){
    errorCallback = successCallback;
    successCallback = data;
    data = null;
}
if(typeof data == 'undefined' || data==null) data = [];
if(!(data instanceof Array)) data = [data];

//we prepend it so reverse order
data.unshift(address);
data.unshift(this.port);
data.unshift(this.host);

cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "OSC", "sendMessage", data);
}

OSCSender.prototype.close = function(successCallback){
    cordova.exec(successCallback, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }, "OSC", "closeSender", [this.host, this.port]);
}

module.exports = OSCSender;
```

I read in the documentation that you don't have do include this within  tags so I didn't. When I did try it out I got the error modules not found.

The next thing I did was creating and instance within my **index.js**.

```
var osc = new OSCSender('test', 'test');
```

I received the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: OSCSender is not defined
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? There is no documentation for this plugin.